# Android: Alarm not starting service

Tags: android, service, android-service, alarmmanager, android-alarms

**Requirement:** Start background service repeatedly

**Design:** Using `AlarmManager`

**What I did:**

```
<service
    android:name=".MyService"
    android:exported="false" >
</service>

AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), SERVICE_ALARM_INTERVAL, pendingIntent);
```

The service class is straight forward `extends Service` with:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {              
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();
    //Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
    mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Service!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.e("tag", "Service!!!");
}
```

**Problem:** The `Toast` message and the `Log` printing not executed.

What I did wrong here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` - this triggers a broadcast. You need to use [PendingIntent.getService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) if you want to trigger a service.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.project.AlarmReceiver" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);

intent.setAction("com.example.project.AlarmReceiver");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);

AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), SERVICE_ALARM_INTERVAL, pendingIntent);
```

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm received!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

AlarmManager will be invoked using broadcast receiver as shown above

Comment: Thanks, actually this is kind of different design but it's working!